# Keyword search extension for Safari 5?

Tags: search, safari

Until Snow Leopard and Safari 5, I loved [Keywurl](http://alexstaubo.github.com/keywurl/). But with Safari 5's new support for extensions, I've been hoping that a replacement would arrive. (Preferably one that doesn't need an InputManager hack to work.)

Is there a keyword search extension for Safari 5 yet? Is it even possible to do?

Comment: See also the similar question for later versions of Safari: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/is-there-an-extension-to-give-safari-the-same-multiple-search-engine-functionali

Answer (score 3):

Looking at a thread on MacRumors, it seems someone has created the closest thing using official Safari Extension API's. I'll try out [KeySearch](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/keysearch/) this weekend.

Comment: KeySearch is okay, but its control-key mapping doesn't work in Safari for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

From [Making Keywurl work with Safari 5](http://hacketal.com/making-keywurl-work-with-safari-5)

> If you've just installed Safari 5 and
>   are also a Keywurl user you may be
>   getting an error regarding Keywurl
>   when starting up Safari (Image 1).
>   I've gotten around this by editing the
>   Info.plist in the Keywurl bundle.
>   Note, these steps are not guaranteed
>   to not cause a problem. Follow at your
>   own risk.
>
> 1. In a Finder window, go to /Library/Application
>      Support/SIMBL/Plugins
> 2. Right-Click Keywurl.bundle and click Show Package Contents
> 3. Right-Click on Info.plist and open it with TextEdit
> 4. Search for the String associated with the Key MaxBundleVersion
> 5. Edit this to match the version number of Safari 5, 6553.6
>
> If Safari is open, you will need to
>   quit completely and re-open.
>
> Click to download:
>   [making-keywurl-work-with-safari-5-gzzCFrviBBmDrzkctdpk.zip](http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/hacketal/zmjwikpEeqycavJlzipvExlunICllJxygxfoxJwDjrACzhtkzsyzfJBdbqhk/making-keywurl-work-with-safari-5-gzzCFrviBBmDrzkctdpk.zip)

NEWS: It seems like a Snow Leopard version of Keywurl is now available from [here](http://alexstaubo.github.com/keywurl/2010/04/01/snow-leopard-support.html).

Comment: This is the same old InputManager hack, and seems to give mixed results. Sounds like the Safari Extension API doesn't give access to the address bar.

Comment: It seems like a Snow Leopard version of Keywurl is now available for download.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is by using [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/), as it has templates for the most popular search engines. So I end up typing:

- `Ctrl` + `Space`: invoke LaunchBar
- `w` to select Wikipedia
- `Space` to enter text mode so I can type the query
- `Enter` when I'm done the query

This will start up a new tab in Safari (or whatever default browser you use) doing the search. The advantage of this approach is that LaunchBar is good for many other things. The disadvantage may be the price, but that's up to you to decide.

[QuickSilver](http://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy/) also does this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually I use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) as a LaunchBar alternative. In Alfred you can define custom web search engines even in free version.

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution that seems to be gaining traction: [Quix](http://quixapp.com/). It's bookmarklet-based, not an extension.

Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

[GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) works as a local proxy that can do [keyword expansion](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/KeywordExpansion) straight from the location bar.